# Usage of the "filter" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

What should [filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) be used for?

This term has two distinct meanings in Drupal.
One refers to content filters ([hook_filter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_filter/6)), and the administrative side of this for non-technical people. The other refers to a feature of the views module for refining queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is now, [filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) is used for both an input filter, which is a component of an input format, and a view filter, which is what filters out the content of a view (as implemented by [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views)).
In the latter case, [filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter) is used together [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views).

As the term is referring to completely different concepts, it would be better to use two different tags, such as [input-filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-filter) for the filters that are part of an input format, and [views-filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views-filter) for a view filter.